# Слово "ученый" имя существительное или имя прилагательное?

Tags: морфология

Слово "ученый" имя существительное или имя прилагательное ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ученый человек. Человек (какой?) ученый - здесь прилагательное. Ученый опубликовал статью. Кто? Ученый - здесь существительное. Это грамматические омонимы. Существительное образовано от прилагательного переходом из одной части речи в другую (неморфологический способ образования). Аналогично столовая ложка - поел в столовой и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо"учитель и ученик" как образовались эти формы,почему нет формы "обучающий",в которой оно было бы существительным как и ученый?

Comment: Есть "учащийся". Например, сравните: "учащийся 2-ого класса" И "мальчик, учащийся во 2-Ом классе"...

Comment: уч/и/тель и уч/еник-от "учить"-суффиксальным способом. Форма "обучающий" вполне могла бы быть, но "учитель" более употребляемая, зачем придумывать новые?Видимо, не привилась. Вот "обучающийся"(канцеляризм)есть, в документах рекомендуют именно эту форму, но учащийся(книжное) и ученик(более разговорное)мне ближе.

Comment: но нет же "учЁник",например,от слова "ученый",откуда "ученик" и "учитель"? почему нельзя использовать все слова как "ученый"либо в форме прилагательного ,либо в форме причастия?

Comment: Это противоречит логике словообразования.Ученик - "это учёный ученик" не соответствует действительности, он не учёный.Ученик-тот, кто учится, т.е. учит себя, учитель - тот, кто учит других.

Comment: я говорю почему нельзя "ученый -учЁник",ну, или другое слово,если можно "учащийся -ученик",почему только форма прилагательного в обоих случаях?

Answer (score 3):

Может быть и существительным (субстантивированное прилагательное) и просто прилагательным. При этом значения у них уже несколько разошлись.
"кот ученый" - это тот кого учили, здесь сохраняются признаки глагольного значения.
В "ученом" (тот, кто занимается наукой) это используется просто как некий признак. 
Сравните: рабочий - находящийся в работе (рабочие чертежи) и рабочий - работающий (человек).

Другим словами, при субстантивации (переходе определения в разряд существительных) возможно смещение представления о субъекте-объекте (или производителе-получателе действия). Если не испугаетесь формулировки - поймете.

А "почему" - это здесь не вопрос. Вопрос - "зачем оно"? Синонимы плодить?

Comment: а зачем тогда синоним "ученик" наплодили для учащегося?

Comment: Наоборот. Ученик был, думаю, раньше - и в достаточно широком значении. 
Ученик лекаря, допустим. Учащимися тогда и не пахло.
А учащийся обозначал только обучающегося в школьном (или подобном) учреждении. Т.н к них значения были несколько разные. Впрочем, это различие и сейчас осталось, может не столь строгое.

Comment: отлично сказано,тогда ответ ,что это существительное образовалось от прилагательного неправильный?

Comment: но  лекарь тоже обучающий...

Answer (score -2):

Есть мнение.
Слово "учёный" обозначает признак предмета и отвечает на вопрос - какой? Отсюда следует, что, согласно русскоязычной логике и правилу языка, слово "учёный" может быть только именем прилагательным. И когда произносят просто слово-прилагательное "учёный", безотносительно к конкретному одушевлённому предмету, то в умолчании, подсознательно, всегда остаётся слово "человек", ибо без этого одушевлённого предмета слово "учёный" является некой абстракцией. При этом само слово "учёный" продолжает обозначать признак предмета, отвечать на вопрос - какой? и, соответственно, оставаться именем прилагательным. Отсюда вполне логично ответить на следующие вопросы так: Он кто? - Человек. А какой он человек? - Учёный. Ведь не отвечают же, например, на вопрос "Он кто?" словом-прилагательным - красивый.